# Java + spring - run actions in infinite loop with random interval

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to simulate a widget that shows purchases in real time.

To increase statistics, I want to supercharge real purchases with fake data, that needs to be emit in random interval.

All the events (real and fake ones) go to the message channel and get processed and then send to frontend.

So I need to come up with some service, that I can control (run and stop)

```
public class FakeDataGenerator {

    private boolean run;
    private Queue queue;

    public void run() {
        run = true;
        while(run) {
            queue.push(generateFakeOne())
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 30));
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        run = false;
    }

    private Purchase generateFakeOne() {
        // ... some faking logic
    }
}

generator.stop();
```

where `generator.run();` will start emitting events with random interval, and `generator.stop();` will allow me to stop it any time

Is there any tool to accomplish such task? I'm not happy with using an infinite loop.

Comment: ¿Have you tried jMeter? You may add some WS endpoint and send data vía jMeter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `spring-boot` why don't try using just `@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)` annotation [example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks)

**Example**

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
 public void scheduleFixedDelayTask() {
System.out.println(
  "Fixed delay task - " + System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
}
```

Comment: Can I control it? Does it expose an API to start/stop the task or amend a random interval range?

Comment: Check this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-batch-start-stop-job, but still i will add an example

Answer (score 0):

Use some of Spring Executor and give it a task to execute. You can control it by the executor reference